# MYSQL Replace data in a column via csv

Tags: mysql, csv

Sorry if this is a duplicate question but Im not quote sure what Im looking for when it comes to MYSQL terminology. Im a WP Developer so this is a little new to me.

I have my _postmeta table with a load of different meta fields. One particular is called "Description". I have downloaded the CSV and replaced the data in the Description content. I now have a CSV with three columns (POST ID, Meta Key (all description) & Meta Value). What I want to do is to use PHPMyAdmin to run a query to update all the current meta values with the content I now have in my CSV.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why not just upload the csv into a table using phpmyadmin and rename the table to "wp_postmeta"

Comment: you could create a work table, do a `LOAD DATA INFILE` into it, then issue an update from one table to another

Comment: That sounds a little more like what Ive been reading but I dont know the first thing about doing that.

Comment: @ParkBroom, what if the real table has 15 columns, and the new one (import) has 3. Just screwed up his database. Create a backup no matter what you do.

Comment: @Drew "wp_postmeta" has 4 columns.  What im suggesting is he just exports "wp_postmeta" as a csv, make the changes and then reupload it using phpmyadmin

Comment: fair enough. hope he is careful no matter what he does :>

Comment: Yea ive done that. Ive made all the changes to the _postmeta csv and saved only the columns I need. But, I have around 30 seperate meta_keys in this table and over 1100 records. The migration of data from the old to the new is hard enough as it is. Ive created a new sheet with the three columns and imported into a new table in the DB. What i need to do now is match postid, to meta_key, to meta_value form my new table and overwrite in the _postmeta table.

Comment: Does anyone have anything to add?